# Can't find Background Processes with GetProcesses()

Tags: c#, process

I have opened 5 instances of an application that I have named in the "Title" of the Form1: "**Hello World**".
So the application is named "Hello World"

In TaskManager, I can see 10 Background processes running like this:
**Hello World (2)

Hello World (2)

Hello World (2)

Hello World (7)

Hello World (2)**

When I run the below code. It only finds one instance which are the one currently running. The other 5 above are OLD instances that for some reason has not closed.
I know that could be backgroundprocesses that still are running.

But important my question is about how to find those 5 processes where I want to .Kill() them. The below code does not find them. What could be missing?

```
void getallprocesses()
{
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses(); String name1 = ""; String name2 = ""; String name3 = "";
    foreach (Process process in processlist)
    {
        //The 5 "Hello World" are not found in name1, name2 or name3
        name1 = process.ProcessName;
        name2 = process.MainWindowTitle;
        name3 = process.MainWindowHandle.ToString();
    }
}
```

Below code also only show the instance that currently is running and not the other 5:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

The file name is a better way to identify a process.

```
        void getallprocesses(string path)
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (string.Compare(process.MainModule.FileName, path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                    {
                        //hit
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Interesting, do you mean that the path is this one which is the .exe file?. I tried to use this code but got an error: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied". Path: "C:/Users/The-PC/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/Hello World/Hello World/bin/Debug/Hello World.exe"

Comment: I also tried to put a try {}catch{} around it. In this case it only found the 1 instance again that currently is running?

Comment: the path is the full path of binary file, this method only finds active processes.